# Call or add on click event in calendar library equinox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/JordanCrown/equinox) js library to show calendar in my page. I have no problem to integrating it. But the problem is i am not seeing any documentation how should i add onclick events in this library! If anyone look at this library and give me any solution, it will be very helpful for me. Thank you.

To Initiate the library i have to use:

```
<div class="event-calendar"></div>
```

then in my script.

```
$('.event-calendar').equinox({
    onEventClick: null,
    onPreviousMonthStart: null,
    onNextMonthStart: null,
    onCurrentMonthStart: null,
    onLoadStart: null,
    onLoadEnd: null
});
```

I was trying to get the current date with on click event, which is related to that library.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give any details about what you want to achieve and what this calendar thing looks like, so don't expect specific answers unless you edit your question.

Anyway, a general solution would be to inspect the calendar widget or element using you browser's dev tools, and check the id of the DOM element you want to target. Once you have the right id, it becomes as simple as:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("element_id");
elem.onclick = function() {
  //whatever you want to do here
}
```

Comment: I updated the code. I want the event that is triggered from library event, not the default one.